# Special characters not passed into controllers action? How can i escape special characters?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-3.0, special-characters

I am passing string having special characters in to contollers action in asp.net mvc3. In action its taking string data as null.

```
var url = '@Url.Action("SetData", "Home")';
var data = { Text: a, Data: urlData };
               $.post(url, data, function (result) {
                });
```

Controllers Action:

```
 public ActionResult SetData(string Text, string Data)
        {
        }
```

My String data is :

```
Content Belongs To Tseries and Eros Entertainment Song : Tum Ho Movie : Rockstar Singer : Mohit Chauhan &amp; Suzzane D&#39; Mello Music By : AR Rahman Rockstar is a
```

How can i pass string having special characters?

Comment: @Thanh Nguyen: I tried encodeURIComponent(), by using this it will encode all my data. Its harmfull to my existing code. Is there any other way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `urlData` variable contains HTML encoded entities. You need to HTML decode it first, like this:

```
var data = {
    text: 'some text',
    data: $('<div/>').html(urlData).text()
};
```

Or maybe change the way you are retrieving the contents of this variable. I think this is where your problem lies essentially.

or on the server side if you prefer (the first solution is recommended):

```
public ActionResult SetData(string text, string data)
{
    var decodedData = Server.HtmlDecode(data);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the javascript function escape on the string data when you place it in you're data object like this

```
var data = { Text: a, Data: escape(urlData) }
```

Comment: Is there any reverese method available fo deescape my urldata? I tried this but it will escape all special characters. This: Url%3Dhttp%3A//www.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3D_xUubHh7vHo%20UrlImage%3Dhttp%3A//img.youtube.com/vi/_xUubHh7vHo/0.jpg%20UrlTitle%3D%20UrlDescription%3DContent%20Belongs%20To%20Tseries%20and%20Eros%20Entertainment%20Song%20%3A%20Tum%20Ho%20Movie%20%3A%20Rockstar%20Singer%20%3A%20Mohit%20Chauhan%20%26amp%3B%20Suzzane%20D%26%2339%3B%20Mello%20Music%20By%20%3A%20AR%20Rahman%20Rockstar%20is%20a. This will harm my existing code.

Comment: I think you should be able to use HttpServerUtility.UrlDecode for this

Comment: jQuery already properly url encodes any data, so no need to do any additional url escaping.

Comment: Darin Dimitrov: But its not working in my code. Is there any alternate solution for that?